# Safe to remove partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I want remove windows from dual boot and want to use ubuntu full time
What partitions can I remove. I don't understand some of the partitions.

```
Partition 1: WINRE_DRV
Partition 2: SYSTEM_DRV
Partition 3: LRS_ESP(
Partition 4: Unknown 128MiB partition
Partition 5: Windows10_OS
Partition 6: ext4
Partition 7: linux-swap
Partition 8: PBR_DRV
Partition 9: Unallocated 1MiB
```

Comment: You should be able to determine whether a partition contains anything you want by mounting it and checking it's contents. A Screenshot of gparted would be a useful [edit] to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-10/Which-partition-should-i-delete-for-Windows-10-Clean-Install/td-p/2150372

First do a full backup of Windows. You paid for it. You may later find you must use Windows for one application or want to sell system and buyer only Wants Windows.

If you do a Lenovo backup it may offer to delete #8 the PBR_DRV.

```
Partition 1: WINRE_DRV - Windows recovery 
Partition 2: SYSTEM_DRV - ESP or required for UEFI boot by all systems.   
Partition 3: LRS_ESP - Lenovo specific .efi files 
Partition 4: Unknown 128MiB partition - required by Windows. 
Partition 5: Windows10_OS - Windows main c: drive 
Partition 6: ext4 -    Linux 
Partition 7: linux-swap 
Partition 8: PBR_DRV- Lenovo backup 
Partition 9: Unallocated 1MiB - not a partition, rounding on unallocated space.
```

If you have done the full backup, you only need 2, 6 & 7 for Ubuntu (and #2 & your data, configuration/settings and list of installed apps in #6 should also be backed up), but then may want /home or data partitions to keep operating system separate from data.